# Adding row_number affects order of rows in rollup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following:

```
CREATE TABLE food_delivery
(
    foodtype varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    foodname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    numitems int NOT NULL
)
go

INSERT INTO food_delivery
VALUES 
('vegetable', 'carrot', 30), 
('vegetable', 'carrot', 50), 
('vegetable', 'potato', 40),
('vegetable', 'potato', 60),
('fruit', 'apple', 50),
('fruit', 'apple', 70),
('fruit', 'banana', 60),
('fruit', 'banana', 80)
GO
```

Now when I run this query:

```
SELECT foodtype, foodname, SUM(numitems)
FROM food_delivery
GROUP BY foodtype, foodname WITH ROLLUP
```

I get this:

```
foodtype     foodname     
------------ ------------ -----------
fruit        apple        120
fruit        banana       140
fruit        NULL         260
vegetable    carrot       80
vegetable    potato       100
vegetable    NULL         180
NULL         NULL         440
```

I'm happy with this ordering, but I also want to add a ranking for the items in each food type, so that I have something like this:

```
foodtype     foodname                 
------------ ------------ ----------- --------------------
fruit        apple        120         1
fruit        banana       140         2
fruit        NULL         260         3
vegetable    carrot       80          1
vegetable    potato       100         2
vegetable    NULL         180         3
NULL         NULL         440         1
```

The idea is that I want to identify the rows that have a ranking of 1 and treat them diffeently.

So this is the query that I use:

```
SELECT foodtype, foodname, SUM(numitems), 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foodtype ORDER BY foodname, SUM(numitems))
FROM food_delivery
GROUP BY foodtype, foodname WITH ROLLUP
```

Unfortunately, adding the ROW_NUMBER() completely throws the ordering of my result set out of whack, and I get this instead:

```
foodtype     foodname                 
------------ ------------ ----------- --------------------
NULL         NULL         440         1
fruit        NULL         260         1
fruit        apple        120         2
fruit        banana       140         3
vegetable    NULL         180         1
vegetable    carrot       80          2
vegetable    potato       100         3
```

i.e. the summaries are at the tops of each group rather than at the bottom.

Can anyone tell me how I can get my summaries at the bottom of each group **while still having my ranking**?

Thanks.

---

EDIT: So Jon Seigel's answer gives me what I want, but I still don't understand why other solutions don't work.

Take this:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN foodtype IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
        foodtype,  
        CASE WHEN foodname IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
        foodname,  
        SUM(numitems),   
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foodtype 

ORDER BY    CASE WHEN foodtype IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
            foodtype, 
            CASE WHEN foodname IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
            foodname DESC)  RankVal 

FROM    food_delivery  
GROUP BY    foodtype,  
            foodname WITH ROLLUP  

ORDER BY    CASE WHEN foodtype IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
            foodtype, 
            CASE WHEN foodname IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
            foodname DESC
```

This is almost identical to Jon's solution, except that I have the order as **descending**, and I transpose the **1** and **0** in **THEN 0 ELSE 1**. To my mind, that should give me the same result (i.e. the NULLS will be 0, and since they are being sorted DESC, they should appear at the bottom of the set). Yet, the result set that is returned is this:

```
            foodtype                 foodname                 RankVal
----------- ------------ ----------- ------------ ----------- --------------------
0           NULL         0           NULL         440         1
1           fruit        0           NULL         260         1
1           fruit        1           banana       140         2
1           fruit        1           apple        120         3
1           vegetable    0           NULL         180         1
1           vegetable    1           potato       100         2
1           vegetable    1           carrot       80          3
```

As you can see, the results from the CASE statement are NOT being sorted in DESCending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    foodtype,
    foodname,
    NumItems,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (
        PARTITION BY foodtype
        ORDER BY
            (CASE WHEN foodtype IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
            foodtype,
            (CASE WHEN foodname IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
            foodname
    ) AS Rank
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            foodtype,
            foodname,
            SUM(numitems) AS NumItems
            FROM food_delivery
            GROUP BY foodtype, foodname WITH ROLLUP
    ) a
    ORDER BY
        (CASE WHEN foodtype IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        foodtype,
        (CASE WHEN foodname IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        foodname
```

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure how to simplify this (if it's even possible), but it does give the desired results you're looking for.

Comment: Jon, your query works, but I honestly I'm still confused as to why. See my edit (I can't post everything in the comment section).

Comment: @Tola: `ASC` and `DESC` apply only to the column where it's specified. I.e., to sort both `foodtype` and `foodname` descending you would `ORDER BY foodtype DESC, foodname DESC`. If neither `ASC` nor `DESC` is specified, it defaults to `ASC`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly specify an `ORDER BY` .

Something like

```
SELECT  foodtype, 
        foodname, 
        SUM(numitems),  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foodtype ORDER BY foodname, SUM(numitems)) RankVal
FROM    @food_delivery 
GROUP BY    foodtype, 
            foodname WITH ROLLUP 

ORDER BY    CASE WHEN foodtype IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
            foodtype,
            CASE WHEN foodname IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
            foodname,
            RankVal
```